# Trying to update an element of an array delete the element instead of actualize it

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

*** I have a sentence in my `index function()` that send a new value to the atribute of my database but when i do it the sentence eliminates the element with the id that i pass to the `index` instead of update it***

- Below i will let the code of my `index function()` and the sentence that give me the problem

***`index function()`***

```php
public function index(Request $request,$id_entrada,$id_venta_entrada,$id_costo,$correo)
    {   
        $detalle_entrada=new Detalle_venta_entrada();
        $detalle_entrada->precio=$id_costo;
        $detalle_entrada->fk_venta_entrada=$id_venta_entrada;
        $detalle_entrada->fk_entrada=$id_entrada;
        $detalle_entrada->save();
        $ventas=new Venta();
        $ventas->monto_total=$id_costo;
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $ventas->fecha_venta=$now->format('d-m-Y');
        $ventas->fk_cliente_natural=1;
        $sub = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT precio_entrada from entrada WHERE id_entrada='$id_entrada'"));
        $subtotal = $sub[0]->precio_entrada;
        $monto = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT precio from detalle_venta_entrada WHERE fk_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada'"));
        $monto_total = $monto[0]->precio;
        $ventas->save();
        $id = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT Max(id_venta) as venta_id from venta"));
        $id_venta = $id[0]->venta_id;
        Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->update(array(
            'disponible'=>'true'
        ));
        $detalle_venta_entrada = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT id_detalle_entrada,precio,
                                                    (select numero_entrada from entrada where id_entrada='$id_entrada'),
                                                    (select fecha from venta_entrada where id_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada'),
                                                    (select monto_total from venta_entrada where id_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada' and fk_cliente_natural=1),
                                                    (select primer_nombre from cliente_natural where id_cliente_natural=1)
                                                    FROM detalle_venta_entrada WHERE fk_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada'and fk_entrada='$id_entrada'"));
        return view ('home.misOrdenes')->with('detalle_venta_entrada',$detalle_venta_entrada)
                                       ->with('id_entrada',$id_entrada)
                                       ->with('id_venta_entrada',$id_venta_entrada)
                                       ->with('detalle_entrada',$detalle_entrada)
                                       ->with('subtotal',$subtotal)
                                       ->with('monto_total',$monto_total)
                                       ->with('id_venta',$id_venta)
                                       ->with('correo',$correo);
    }
```

*** sentence that give me the problem***

```php
Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->update(array(
            'disponible'=>'true'
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change it to. I don't think there needs to be array

```
Entrada::where('id_entrada'=>$id_entrada)->update(array(
        'disponible'=>'true'
    ));
```

Comment: Yes but how? i tried other way but it happen the same thing

Comment: it is not updating the record ?

Comment: No , deletes the record and i dont know why

Comment: Also tried this `$update = Entrada::find($id_entrada);
        $update->disponible = 'true';
        $update->save();`

Comment: $request_updated_status   = Entrada::where('id',$id_entrada);
$request_status_data['disponible '] = 'true';
$request_updated_status->update($request_status_data);

Comment: try this one please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205722/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-rinzler21).

Comment: still doesn't work, keep delething the element i dont know why

Comment: I guess the issue is with the cascading on your structure. This will help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql

Comment: Now it works, the thing that happen is the Entrada get actualized but send the updated Entrada to the bottom of the list in my bd, i have 150 registers in that table so i didn't notice that , i dont know why send the actualize it to botttom of the list in the table but it works

Comment: Great it’s a learning one. An upvote as well please I’ll do the same. Thanks